# heroku/cli.rb:30:in `start': undefined method `error_with_failure'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, heroku, web-deployment

I was wrestling with ssh keys and uploaded a new one, then I git push heroku master'ed fine, then it displays my landing page but shows

```
 We're sorry, but something went wrong.
```

I found in stackoverflow that it might be that I haven't yet run

```
 heroku rake db:migrate
```

(which no standard documentation says to do!) but when I run that I get this:

```
 User/<computername>/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/cli.rb:30:in `start': undefined method `error_with_failure' 
 for Heroku::Helpers:Module (NoMethodError)from /usr/bin/heroku:28
```

the code for this file looks like this:

```
def self.start(*args)
begin
  if $stdin.isatty
    $stdin.sync = true
  end
  if $stdout.isatty
    $stdout.sync = true
  end
  command = args.shift.strip rescue "help"
  Heroku::Command.load
  Heroku::Command.run(command, args)
rescue Interrupt
  `stty icanon echo`
  error("Command cancelled.")
rescue => error
if Heroku::Helpers.error_with_failure <<<<<<<<< Line #30 WHERE ERROR OCCURS  
    display("failed")
    Heroku::Helpers.error_with_failure = false
  end
  $stderr.puts(' !    Heroku client internal error.')
  $stderr.puts(" !    Search for help at: https://help.heroku.com")
  $stderr.puts(" !    Or report a bug at: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/new")
  $stderr.puts
  $stderr.puts("    Error:       #{error.message} (#{error.class})")
  $stderr.puts("    Backtrace:   #{error.backtrace.first}")
  error.backtrace[1..-1].each do |line|
    $stderr.puts("                 #{line}")
  end
```

Comment: Are you using the cedar stack? If so, that command is wrong; it should be `heroku run rake db:migrate`

Comment: I'm on version heroku-gem/2.28.12 (universal-darwin11.0) ruby/1.8.7

I am running cedar stack and tried heroku run rake db:migrate, same error :o(

Comment: What does `heroku logs` tell you? Are you using the heroku gem or heroku toolbelt?  (https://toolbelt.herokuapp.com/)

Comment: Are you sure you're currently running Ruby 1.8.7? The heroku toolbelt (I didn't install the gem) doesn't seem to play well with Ruby 1.9.x, returning that very error. Switching to Ruby 1.8.7 resolved the issue for me.

Comment: I am using the toolbelt. I'm a nube and stay away from changing my ruby version, would just switching to using the heroku gem be another solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen something like this come up as a conflict of having BOTH gem and toolbelt installs and Ruby confusing what to load from when.  If you would like to use toolbelt I highly recommend uninstalling any gem versions you might have to avoid this (and likely everything should work for you at that point).  You can do this by running `gem uninstall heroku` and choosing to uninstall all versions.  If you are still experiencing issues let me know though and I'll be happy to continue helping to troubleshoot.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please update the heroku gem. It's probably an issue in the particular version you have installed.

Comment: Listen to @geemus, he knows what he's talking about

Answer (score 0):

Run in the same problem with `heroku run rake db:migrate`.
It seems that the toolbelt is unable to find the `Heroku::Helpers.error_with_failure` helper.

Remove your heroku toolbelt folder with

`rm -rf /usr/local/heroku`

and the executable with

`sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/heroku`.

Then try reinstalling the toolbelt from [here](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/)

This solved for me.